# How to get the nest tags as string rather actual nest tags using PHP(DOM)?

Tags: php, dom

Consider the xml

```
<data>
 <node1>
        some text some text <nested-node>nest node content</nested-node> some text
 </node1>
</data>
```

Want to access `<node1>` tag (that i can do), But i want to get  content as follow...

```
some text some text &lt;nested-node&gt;nest node content &lt;/nested-node&gt; 
some text
```

Please help me how can I achieve this???

Comment: Perhaps you should google at first and when you have a real problem to solve this exercise you can write here. Solution: Read the XML and make a html escape.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your XML on top is not well formed.

You cannot use tags in a text sequence. The parser remove such elements.

[XML Escaping](http://xmmssc-www.star.le.ac.uk/SAS/xmmsas_20070308_1802/doc/param/node24.html)

[List of escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

With this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('xmltest.xml'));
var_dump($xml->node1);
```

you can read the node.

Answer (score 0):

I got curious of this question. Is it really impossible to do what what OP wants? @Stony noted that malformed XML makes this impossible, and I wouldn't be surprised if the XML functions won't work with malformed XML in the way OP wants.

Here's an example of nesting element in XML: http://www.featureblend.com/xml-nesting.html

If you form your XML like this:

```
<data>
  <master_node>
    <nested1>First nested node text.</nested1>
    <nested2>Second nested node text.</nested2>
    <nested3>Third nested node text.</nested3>
  </master_node>
</data>
```

You are able to get all the text contents:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('xmltest.xml'));
var_dump($xml->master_node);
```

Maybe it's possible to something similar with JavaScript or plain PHP. Just load the file into variable and parse it with regex or string search functions. Parsing XML with regex, yes I know, it's like parsing HTML with regex, a big no-no...

Comment: hmmm... Thank you for your guidance ... I am also thinking to load the file and then replace the nested tags with i.e. to convert them to string data...

Comment: @Shahid That would be one way to go. I didn't have time to test earlier how to get this element's tags outputted as entities: `<nested2>nested node &lt;encoded_tag&gt;content&lt;/encoded_tag&gt; after encoded</nested2>`. It prints nicely on a page but of course without the tags. Try with `<nested2>nested node &lt;strong&gt;content&lt;/strong&gt; after encoded</nested2>` and you see the tags content is formatted accordinly – i.e. the tags are in the source code.